# Trying to serve images that are downloaded on the spot in Express Middleware

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, download, middleware

I'm having a hard time with express and middleware.
Basically what I'm trying to do is serve an image on disk but if it does not exists, download it from some external server, and then serve/display it. The second and following requests to the image will then serve the image from disk.

So downloading is not the issue, the issue is serving the image right after it's been downloaded.
Using the code below, will result in all images being downloaded and some images shown in the browser. But it will rain messages saying:

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

TLDR;
I'm having two issues:

- I get messages like:Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
- Not all my images will be shown in the browser, although all images have been downloaded in the correct location on disk.

**extra info:**

the images are served from \public\files
I'm using NextJS with a custom server.js
I'm not sure if I need to end the response after the sendFile. I know the server.all('*') gives the Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. But I'm not sure how to mitigate that problem since doing something like this:

```
  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    if(!req.url.startsWith('/files')){
      return handle(req, res)
    }
  })
```

made things worse, and would make images disappear that had already been downloaded, and worked before. So than I got to think that I need to ALWAYS do sendFile, but then I seemed not to be able to await the download in the catch and would spit out errors like:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

I'll share the middleware with you guys:

```
var download = async function (from, to, callback) {
    await createDirectory(to);
    let fileStream = fsclassic.createWriteStream(to);
    request(from).pipe(fileStream).on('close', callback);
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.use('/files', async (req, res, next_middleware) => {
    var file = path.join(__dirname, "public\\files", req.url);
    
    try{
        await fs.access(file, fsclassic.constants.F_OK);
    }catch(e) {
        await download(internalToExternal(req.url), file, () => {
            res.status(200).sendFile(file);
        });
    }

    next_middleware();
  })

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

So I've got an answer to my own question.
I've changed the handling of the file.access call to not use try: catch.

when the file exists I call next_middleware() which will handle over control to the server.all('*')

when the file has been downloaded, I do the same, which will also handle control over to the server.all('*')

this will result in images being displayed when they have been downloaded, and when revisiting the site.

code:

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.use('/files', async (req, res, next_middleware) => {
    var file = path.join(__dirname, "public\\files", req.url);
    var options = {
      root: __dirname + "\\public\\files"
    }

    fs.access(file, fsclassic.constants.F_OK).then(() => {
      next_middleware();
    }).catch(async () => {
      await download(internalToExternal(req.url), file, () => {
        next_middleware();
      });
    });
  })

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```